# Does Stokes law on a non-conservative field?

Tags: vector-fields, stokes-theorem, curl

I was trying to check if Stokes would hold in a field $(3x^2y^3,-x^3y^2)$ (non conservative as curl is non zero) for the figure below but I got that LHS (the surface integral) was not equal to RHS (line integral) in Stokes law. So does that mean that Stokes law does not always hold?

[image]

### EDIT: added my attempt

[image]
[image]

Comment: Stokes theorem always holds (provided the functions are smooth enough and the domains are nice enough, which in your case they are). Stokes theorem (or more precisely its consequences) is a **test** for conservativeness; not the other way around, i.e conservative/not conservative has nothing to do with the validity of Stokes theorem. The fact that the field is not conservative just means that the line integral over the closed loop isn't necessarily $0$. But so what? That just means the surface integral is also not necessarily $0$, but the two quantities will still be equal.

Comment: Do you mean Green's theorem? Also if the vector field was conservative, both LHS and RHS would be zero.

Comment: If you share your working, we can check your mistake.

Comment: @MathLover, ok will do. Please give me a minute to upload.

Comment: @MathLover, no its Stokes: $$\int_S \nabla \times \overline{A} \overline{ds} = \oint_C \overline{A} \cdot \overline{dl} $$. S is open surface and C is a closed line. The lines are supposed to represent that these are vectors. Sorry not sure how to make them pretty.

Comment: Let me check your working.

Comment: Your logic and bounds all look sound, it must just be some algebra error somewhere. Edit: Scratch that, your line integrals have double negatives. You should not be accounting for backward motion both in the $dr$ and the bounds, you must reverse one or the other .

Comment: @NinadMunshi, hmm I don't see where I do the error unfortunately. Is it when I calculate on of the the straight lines?

Comment: Have you seen the edited version of my comment? Refresh the page if necessary.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, yes indeed. So my bounds should not be like 3 to 1 but instead 1 to 3?

Comment: That is one way to fix it, yes.

Comment: First of all, is your vector field $(3x^2y^2, -x^3y^2)$? Your working has a different vector field.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, but why should one do that, I am thinking I have to somehow tell that the line is going down, and that the unit vector is pointing down?

Comment: @MathLover, yes indeed I wrote wrong in my question, sorry.

Comment: We know that vector line integrals must evaluate to be of the opposite sign when you move backwards along a curve as opposed to forward. But if you changed both you would get that $$\int_{-C}F\cdot (-dr) = \int_CF\cdot dr \neq - \int_C F\cdot dr$$

Comment: Then your double integral is correct but the sign is wrong. It should be positive.

Comment: @MathLover, really? I tried it with wolfram and got this: https://imgur.com/yIwDE7J  or maybe the curl was wrong?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, oh I didn't notice I hade to take that into consideration. So since I am going in counter-clockwise direction I must have a minus to the bounds.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, thank you all for your help by the way!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the curve is clockwise oriented, the normal vector is $(0, 0, -1)$ and the double integral should evaluate to $\displaystyle \small \frac{1352}{3}$.

For the line integral,

$\vec F = (3x^2y^3,-x^3y^2)$ and we have $3$ line segments $y = 1, x \in(3,1); \ y = x, x \in (1, 3); \ x = 3, y \in(3,1)$

$I = \displaystyle \small \int_3^1 (3x^2,-x^3) \cdot (1, 0) \ dx + \int_1^3 (3x^5,-x^5) \cdot (1, 1) \ dx + \int_3^1 (27y^3,-27y^2) \cdot (0, 1) \ dy$

$ = \displaystyle \small \int_3^1 3x^2\ dx + \int_1^3 2x^5 \ dx + \int_3^1 -27y^2 \ dy$

$ = \displaystyle \small -26 + \frac{728}{3} + 234 = \frac{1352}{3}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I should have written? $$ \int_S 12x^2y^2 \overline{a}_z \cdot (0,0,-1) \cdot \overline{a}_z dx dy $$. My math notation sucks sorry. Is that the correct way to write it? Or does the $(0,0,-1)$ come with dx dy (differential surface element)?

Comment: you should have written $(0, 0, -12x^2y^2) \cdot (0, 0, -1)$.

Comment: Like this? $$ \int_S (0,0,-12x^2y^2) \cdot (0,0,-1) dx dy $$

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.